# Randomizing NetworkX output

Tags: python, random, networkx

Suppose I have a `nx.Graph` object `g` that has two or more cycles. If I call `nx.find_cycle`, the output is always the same. I wonder if there is a built-in way to randomize the output, say, by accessing the NetworkX internal random state. The `find_cycles` function is just an example, I am interested in randomizing output of other NetworkX functions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_cycle` begins searching for cycles at an arbitrary node, and returns the first cycle it finds.  `find_cycle` takes a `source` argument, which tells the algorithm the node that it should start at.  So, to randomize the output, you can simply randomize the source node.

```
import random

s = random.choice(G.nodes())
cycle = find_cycle(G, source = s)
```